# Error on sql-dev "date format picture ends before converting entire input string", not on toad

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

Hello I have this query to get the first day of the month :

```
select concat(  REPLACE(TRUNC(to_date(CURRENT_DATE, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'mm') ,TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'yy'), ''),TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'yyyy')) from dual
```

But when I execute it SQL DEVELOPER I got error ORA-01830

And when I execute it on toad I got the good result :
'01-FEB-2020'

How can I do to be worked on these two environnement

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason for doing a simple thing in such a complex manner? The result you need is

```
select trunc(current_date, 'mm') from dual;
```

---

By the way, `current_date` is a function that returns `date` so `TO_DATE`-ing it is wrong.